# Problem when debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I'm facing with a big problem when debugging my android project.
There are some code that really ran but break point is not hit.
So i cannot debug my project.
Can I help me in this situation.
Thanks

Comment: Clean your project and build it again. Then debug it.

Comment: some code are able to debug and some code are not. When i use logcat, it is ok. But i need to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the following property in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Comment: some code are able to debug and some code are not. I have set android:debuggable="true"
but it make no change.

Comment: of the same application then it might be the flow of your app never goes to that place

Comment: im sure that my app go to this place that i take breakpoint. Because of logcat.